# pasar propiedades de un componente a otro en reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, props

Soy nuevo en `Reactjs` y tengo unas cuantas dudas me piden refactorizar este código:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const App = () => {
  const course = 'Half Stack application development'
  const part1 = 'Fundamentals of React'
  const exercises1 = 10
  const part2 = 'Using props to pass data'
  const exercises2 = 7
  const part3 = 'State of a component'
  const exercises3 = 14

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{course}</h1>
      <p>
        {part1} {exercises1}
      </p>
      <p>
        {part2} {exercises2}
      </p>
      <p>
        {part3} {exercises3}
      </p>
      <p>Number of exercises {exercises1 + exercises2 + exercises3}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Me piden hacer 3 componentes *Header*, *Content*, *Total* ya he realizado el Header y el Content
El problema esta en que el componente Content tiene unas `props` y en el componente total debo llamar a esa propiedades que son números y sumarlos, quería saber como puedo acceder a las propiedades del Componente Content desde el Componente Total.

Adjunto mi código hasta ahora:

```
function Header() {  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Half Stack application development</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

function Content(props) { // father 
  const {number,number1,number2} = props; //desestructuring 
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Fundamentals of React {number}</p>
      <p>Using props to pass data {number1}</p>
      <p>State of a component {number2}</p>
    </div>
  );
}



// como acceder a las propiedades de un componente desde otro componente
function Total() { // child the Contend
  return(
    <p>Number of exercies</p>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
    <Header/>
    <Content number = '20' number1='2' number2 ='5'/>
    <Total/>
    </Fragment>        
  );
}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Tienes que hacer exactamente lo mismo que estas haciendo en tu componente Content ;)

Comment: ¿Conoces [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) o [React Context](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/context.html)? Creo que alguna de esas podría ser la solución a tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Para lograrlo, y dado que Total es hijo de Component, puedes renderizar Total dentro del return de Component. Allí puedes pasarle los atributos:

```
    function Content(props) { // father 
        const {number,number1,number2} = props; //desestructuring 
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Fundamentals of React {number}</p>
                <p>Using props to pass data {number1}</p>
                <p>State of a component {number2}</p>
                <Total numbers={number, number1, number2}>
                </Total>
            </div>
        );
  }
```

Definiendo el objeto total como:

```
function Total(props) { // child the Contend
    exerciseNumber = props.numbers.reduce((n1, n2) => n1 + n2)
    return (
        <p>Number of exercies</p>
    );
}
```

A pesar de que así funcionará, para este tipo de cometidos en el que las funciones van a ser componentes del DOM puede ser interesante definirlos como componentes de React, del estilo:

```
class Total extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.exerciseNumber = props.numbers.reduce((n1, n2) => n1 + n2)
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <p>Number of exercies</p>
        );
    }
}
```